# Multiple Accounts - opening bounty on question

Tags: discussion, bounties, multiple-accounts

I've searched through most of the multiple-accounts tag and as far as I can understand, the policy is that its okay to have multiple accounts provided they don't interact or sockpuppet.

Now I have two accounts, one which I use for work, the other which I use at home (reason I use two is that I don't trust logging into my personal Google account at work). Since I can't use work-time to answer questions, the work one has very low rep.

Is it acceptable to use one account to open a bounty on a question which the other account has asked? I'm not talking about using it to transfer rep or something, but more on line with "I'd like this question to receive a bounty, but my other account has too low rep to do it".

Comment: I see no problem with it personally, unless you were planning to use it to rep transfer (but you've said you aren't).

Comment: ... although thinking about it @Mansfield, is using it for rep transfer that bad either? They're his accounts. It's reputation he's earnt.

Comment: @Matt It's specifically prohibited to transfer rep to other accounts you own, actually.

Comment: @Servy: Have you got a link for that? Google doesn't show much.

Comment: @Matt the extra attention for a question through bounties comes at a cost. If you were to transfer rep via bounties, that would eliminate the cost, while still getting you the attention. That would at the very least be an abuse of the system.

Comment: @Bart: I hear you there.

Comment: fyi, if you just have separate accounts so you don't have to access your google account at work: you could use e.g. the stackexchange openid or any other openid provider and use it only for stackoverflow

Comment: You can have more than one OpenID provider for the same account and login with one of them.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think that sounds fine. It's your reputation that you earned. You should be able to spend it on trying to get any question answered that you like.  What you're proposing doesn't seem much different than donating reputation for a bounty on a question asked by a co-worker or family member.